# Unable to start ambari-metrics monitor

Tags: ambari

I change my ambari metrics monitor configuration from embedded to distributed and restarted service ,but getting below error in one of the host

```
On host <hostname> role METRICS_MONITOR in invalid state.
Invalid transition. Invalid event: HOST_SVCCOMP_OP_IN_PROGRESS at UNKNOWN
```

I am unable to understand what change i should make to get this working

Answer (score 0):

```
update ambari.hostcomponentstate set current_state='INSTALLED' where component_name = 'METRICS_MONITOR' and current_state = 'INIT';
```

then restart ambari-server and ambari-agent. Reapply your changes.

Ref: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/10246/error-role-in-invalid-state.html